# Using azure sdk for .net to create Container Groups for ACI, creation times out after 30 seconds. How to set timeout?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-container-instances

Using azure sdk for .net to create Container Groups for ACI, we get the following exception when the task takes > 30 seconds. What's the proper configuration to avoid this timeout?

```
var azure = new AsyncLazy<IAzure>(() => Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
    .Configure()
    .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.BodyAndHeaders)
    .Authenticate(credentials)
    .WithDefaultSubscriptionAsync());

IAzure az = await azure.GetValueAsync();

await az.ContainerGroups.Define()....CreateAsync();
```

=>

```
{"Long running operation failed with status 'Canceled'."}
   at Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.LRO.AzureLRO`2.CheckForErrors()
   at Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.LRO.PutLRO`2.CheckForErrors()
   at Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.LRO.AzureLRO`2.<StartPollingAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.LRO.AzureLRO`2.<BeginLROAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Rest.Azure.AzureClientExtensions.<GetLongRunningOperationResultAsync>d__1`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Rest.Azure.AzureClientExtensions.<GetLongRunningOperationResultAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Rest.Azure.AzureClientExtensions.<GetPutOrPatchOperationResultAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent.ContainerGroupsOperations.<CreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent.ContainerGroupsOperationsExtensions.<CreateOrUpdateAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent.ContainerGroupImpl.<CreateResourceAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.ResourceActions.Creatable`4.<Microsoft-Azure-Management-ResourceManager-Fluent-Core-ResourceActions-IResourceCreator<IResourceT>-CreateResourceAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.DAG.CreatorTaskItem`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.DAG.TaskGroupBase`1.<ExecuteNodeTaskAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
```